# "pip freeze > requirements.txt" is not taking the latest commit from github

Tags: python, django, git, github

I have committed some new bugfixes into a branch from where I pull the latest state into my virtualenvs using requirements.txt

till now, there was this in requirements.txt

```
-e git+https://github.com/socialsweethearts/django-allauth.git@da237e5ab336b7d8c5ba49a6b2f64589e077ea90#egg=django_allauth-origin_nametest_patch
```

`da237e5ab336b7d8c5ba49a6b2f64589e077ea90` being the hash of latest commit in github

but now, after my latest push, the branch has now new hash, namely `0fbac17f59ea52ab906214e9e2b4b9017e5adc89`.

now, I did `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but my requirements.txt is not updating to latest commit hash. why is it? am I missing something?

Comment: Did you actually install the new version (`0fbac17f59ea52ab906214e9e2b4b9017e5adc89`)? Or did you push it to Github?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco ah you are right, I need to install it first on my own locally and only then it will be mapped to requirements.txt, right? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip freeze` essentially just writes out what is **currently** installed in your environment. The old version is still installed, so that's the one `pip freeze` writes out.

If you want to update your `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze`, you should:

- Install the new version
- Run `pip freeze`

---

Alternatively, you could update the commit hash in `requirements.txt` manually and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to update the installed package.

Comment: haha thanks man, I had total blackout, you are absolutely right